# When can I book a ticket for 1 November 2023 on renfe.es for Madrid to Badajoz?

Tags: trains, spain

I am trying to book a ticket from Madrid to Badajoz on https://www.renfe.com/es/en for Wednesday 1 November 2023 and the search results are empty.

There are results e.g. for Wednessday 11 October 2023.

Also there are results for Zamora to Madrid on Wednesday 1 November 2023.

Comment: Renfe is not prompt about adding its trains to its online ticket portal; it's likely that they haven't yet added the trains you want, and thus you're trying to book too early. Read the [Seat61](https://www.seat61.com) specific paragraphs on [Tips for Buying Train Tickets](https://www.seat61.com/european-train-tickets-online.htm) including the "Long Distance Trains in...Spain" and the "How Far in Advance Can I Book" segments. I had this issue earlier in 2023 with several inside-Spain trains.

Comment: Check https://www.seat61.com/european-train-booking-horizons.htm

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Good catch!